# Can a JIT take a benefit from Generics?

Tags: java, optimization, jit

It is well known, that generic types don't survive the compiling process. They are replaced by class casts.

But nevertheless, the type information is present in the class file and can be seen using reflection:

```
public class Demo
{
    private List<String> list;

    public Demo() throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException
    {
        System.out.println(((Class<?>)((ParameterizedType) getClass().getDeclaredField("list").getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException
    {
        new Demo();
    }
}
```

When executed, this will print `java.lang.String`.

Can a JIT use this for some kind of optimization? Or is that information from the point of view of the JIT useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could, but as far as I know it doesn't. To work around this, Scala added support somewhat recently to compile-time [type specialization](http://blog.m1key.me/2010/03/programming-scala-28-showcase-type.html) of generic code which generates specialized versions of the class - without any casts - and places them to the rest of the codebase transparently so that the code still works as expected. In these cases, compiled Scala code can actually be noticeably faster than Java since Java with Generics will always use casts.

Comment: But that has a negative impact on memory usage, because there is more code, is there not?

Comment: Yep, it's a trade-off. Memory isn't the scarcest of resources nowadays though.

Comment: @yankee Sure, but then C++ templates do have this problem all along and so far it has worked fine for them. Although that has also to do with some clever optimizations (ie methods that result in the same machine code are combined), which I doubt the Java compiler does (that's a non trivial problem and javac is quite simple)

Comment: @Voo javac may be simple, but that's just because the heavy lifting is done by JIT and runtime. They both do an insane amount of optimizations and de-optimizations to produce the best possible actual running machine code, bytecode generated by javac is *just* intermediary.

Comment: @Esko Yeah the JIT does the heavy lifting, but at a point in time where I think it'd be quite complicated (or at least quite costly) to fold methods at runtime. And javac's goal is to be a simple compiler - this kind of optimization we're talking about would go against this principle. And as a matter of fact afaik the Hotspot source, nothing is done in the regard (probably because scala isn't that important for them)

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible for the JVM to avoid casting the object as the underlying collection may not have Strings. e.g. if erasure is used to add an Integer to the list.

I can't think of a potential optimisation and there are plenty of potential optimisation the JIT doesn't do. ;)